# CSS transparent borders

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm trying to create a css ribbon like this:

[image]

It works fine with the following code.

```css
body {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/FgqcKXm.jpg') no-repeat;
}
h1 {
  background: #A52927;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 30px;
  color: #EEE4D3;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
h1:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0px;
  left: auto;
  right: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid white;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1>test</h1>
```

**Problem:**
It displays the white border on non-white  background:

[image]

Is there any alternative way to get the same shape on non-white background with css only?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jnzgsfp/)

Comment: why -1? what's wrong with the question?

Comment: The only reason I can see for the downvotes is because you didn't include the HTML in the question itself but it definetly doesn't deserve downvotes as issue is clear.

Comment: another way you can use `skew(x)` for pseudo elements [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jnzgsfp/4/)

Comment: I had a play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/5jnzgsfp/5/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just give this way:

```css
h1:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 0px;
    left: auto;
    right: -20px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    border-top: 20px solid #A52927;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #A52927;
}
```

**Preview:**

[image]

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5jnzgsfp/3/**